# git push giving errors

Tags: github, git-push

My repository name at my local machine is "firsthand". I have made some changes to my file (named "index.html") and have committed them to my local repository. Now I want to commit those changes to my remote repository using **git push**. But when i do, it is giving me following errors. (My username at www.github.com is shobhit9192@gmail.com). Plz help

C:\Users\SHOBIT\firsthand>git push
To https://github.com/shobhit9192/firsthand.git

! [rejected]        gh-pages -> gh-pages (fetch first)

error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/shobhit9192/firsthand.git'

hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do

hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing

hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes

hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.

hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: Have u tried to use `git pull`?

Answer (score 0):

This indicates someone else has pushed work you do not currently have on your local repository.

You will have to integrate the remote changes (like the hint said) before you can push local changes.

(i've only tried this on the linux command-line, since I don't use windows)

Try:

```
git fetch origin

git pull origin (brachname)

git push origin (brachname)
```

Please attempt to read the hints/error messages, they are often self-explanatory.